# How To SetUP SOCKS5 Proxy Server on Linux based OS

Tags: linux, security, proxy, bsd, socks

What is the best way to setup SOCKS5 proxy server on *nix?

I have tried a lot of solutions but really not impressed

For instance one GO-based solution just not working, another option is to use ssh tunnels but it's not so convenient

Could you help me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need

All *nix platforms supported

And also almost all popular BSD forks

Native management of SOCKS5 proxy server...

https://github.com/ksukhorukov/SOCKS

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).